# Does the Acer Iconia Tab A500 support Accessory mode?

Tags: android, arduino, tablet, adk

I have an [Acer Iconia Tab A500](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acer_Tablet#Iconia_Tab_A500) with stock [Honeycomb 3.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history#3.1), and a Google [ADK](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/adk.html). I haven't been able to get the ADK to communicate with the tablet in Accessory mode, and I can't find any information that states whether the tablet supports this mode.

I've contacted Acer support, but I have not received a satisfactory response (they misunderstood me and answered that it supports USB Host mode, and haven't responded to my request for more accurate information)

Update: In addition to the information below, I received an official response from Acer technical support:

> This issue was sent to our engineers. The unit currently does not
>   support USB Accessory mode; however, we are planning to release an
>   update that adds this functionality. Unfortunately, we are unable to
>   determine when this update will become available. I apologize for the
>   inconvenience.

If I receive any followup indication that they've implemented support I will post it here.

Answer (score 2):

Presently it does not, but we have been in touch with Acer about this issue and a fix is forthcoming.

Comment: Did they happen to give an ETA?

Comment: Hard to make a decision with that information about keeping or swapping my tablet for a Xoom. "forthcoming" could mean days or months.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that the ADK DOES NOT work with the Acer A500 running 3.1. However, the Acer A100 running 3.2 does. Hopefully when the A500 gets a 3.2 update things will work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I spoke with Acer Support and the guy said that they support the ADK and it should work with 3.1.  Said if your having issues, call 1-800-571-2237, (Monday to Friday 8 am to 8 pm CST)

Answer (score 0):

3.2 ROMs do support accessory mode - I have got the demokit example working using "Taboonay 2.0" ROM, you can find instructions in the xda-developers forum.